# How to edit this macro so that only C2:C20 get exported to Notepad as .txt file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro that runs when a button is clicked but when it, it also exports column A2:A200. How do I make it so that it only exports the content in range C2:C20?

```
Sub CrText()


Dim c00            As Variant
Dim textFilePath   As String
Dim lngCounter     As Long
Dim FF             As Integer


textFilePath = CStr(VBA.CurDir) & "\mTextFile.txt"


FF = VBA.FreeFile
c00 = Range("C2:C20").CurrentRegion


Open textFilePath For Output As #FF
    For lngCounter = LBound(c00, 1) To UBound(c00, 1)
        Print #FF, Join(Application.Index(c00, lngCounter, 0), vbTab)
    Next
Close #FF
Shell "C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe " & textFilePath, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`CurrentRegion` is expanding the range to all the contiguous cells connected to `Range("C2:C20")`.

Use `Range("C2:C20").Value` instead or simply `Range("C2:C20")` as `.Value` is returned by default.

> ```
>  c00 = Range("C2:C20").Value
> ```